# HKHostFreezeCkptTrimming on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, error-log, memory-optimized-tables

Have a SQL Server 2017 Standard edition box with build 14.0.3045.24 with one memory-optimized table. When our 3rd party backups complete the SQL Server 2017 error log shows several [INFO] messages containing **HKHostFreezeCkptTrimming(), HKHostBackupDeleteContext(), getMaxUnrecoverableCheckpointID()** and with the same user database ID. Any of you familiar with these messages? Is this a bug or is there a fix for these messages?

Additional testing has shown these [INFO] messages appears during full, differential, transaction log, and manual copy-only backups. Performance is good and users aren't complaining, but considering the amount of backups that are required these messages are filling the error log.

Anything I can do to limit the entry of these messages to the error log? Or is this a case of dealing with additional messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have an answer for what exactly they mean, but I see them on every machine where I have a memory optimized file group.

Since they start with "HK" they seem to be related to [In-Memory OLTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017) (codenamed **H**e**k**aton prior to the production release in SQL Server 2014).

I would say that since they are INFO messages, and they are common on instances with memory optimized filegroups, that they are nothing to worry about.

There isn't currently a documented way of disabling those messages, and I hear that there really is no undocumented way of disabling them either.  There *is* a precedent for disabling backup-related info messages (see [trace flag 3226](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)), so you could make a request on user voice: [SQL Server Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server)